# Why is this HTML/CSS based drop-down menu going out of the container?

Tags: css

[Already posted this question once but didn't get any significant response so posting it again.]
HTML

```
<div class="menu" id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a class="home" id="home" href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="about" id="about" href="">About Us</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About us1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About us2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About usn</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="prod" id="prod" href="">Products</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Product1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Product2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Product3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="contact" id="contact" href="">Contact</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Contact1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Contact3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="program" id="program" href="">Programmes</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Program1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Program2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="gallery" id="gallery" href="">Galleries</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Photo Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Video Gallery</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a class="gallery" id="gallery" href="">Downloads</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Download1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Download2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS of my div wrapper

```
div.wrapper 
{
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #999;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #999;
    -msie-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #999;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #999;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -o-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -msie-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
    width: 1024px; 
    height: 1400px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

CSS of my drop-down menu

```
div.menu
{
    font-family: serif, Verdana, Geneva, Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 45px;
    width: 1024px;
    background-color: #06472F;
    -msie-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
    display: table-cell;
}

div.menu ul 
{
    font-size: 24px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

div.menu ul li 
{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}

div.menu ul li ul 
{
    display: none;
}

div.menu ul li a 
{
    border-radius: 2px;
    -msie-border-radius: 2px;
    -o-border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border-top: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    background: #06472F;
    margin-left: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div.menu ul li a:hover 
{
    color: #FFFF00;
}

div.menu li:hover ul 
{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

div.menu li:hover li 
{
    float: none;
    font-size: 25px;
}

div.menu li:hover li a:hover 
{
    background-color: #000000;
    color: #FFFF00;
}
```

Now, when I use Chrome and zoom-out, when it reaches 33%, it actually goes to the next line. How may I prevent this using only CSS?

I've tried changing the size, but then it leaves out extra gap at the end of the menu and that is not what I want. I also tried wrapping the whole menu up in another div tag, but it didn't work. I also tried making all the sizes relative, using '%', still, it didn't work. Help?

Comment: Would you add a jsfiddle link so we could see a working example?

Comment: I've given you that Pastie's link for an example and I don't need any JS just yet. I just used once JS event because I couldn't find any alternative.

Comment: Ya, like I stated in the first line: "I didn't get a significant response."

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vNYV8/ this is the fiddle

Comment: Its working fine in my browser, i dont know what wrong

Comment: Try using Chrome and zooming out. My resolution is 2048*1152.

EDIT: Try using the full file provided in that Pastie link, don't use  the CSS and the HTML **only** of the menu.

Comment: Regardless of the disclaimer, it's not appropriate to repost the same question to get more attention. Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: @TimMedora Thanks, I'll keep that in mind next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
div.menu   change height 45px to 35px  -  height: 35px;
```

and

```
div.menu ul   change font-size 24px to 20px - font-size: 20px;

div.menu ul
{
font-size: 20px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}


div.menu{
font-family: serif, Verdana, Geneva, Arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
height: 35px;
width: 1024px;
background-color: #06472F;
-msie-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
-o-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: No, it decrease the size, but still, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you show your screen short?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/xwdkdfb2r/

Comment: Also, if you could test it in a screen of resolution around 1024*800 and give me a screen shot of it, it would mean a lot, thanks. :)